Transposing multiple values columns in Pandas
I have the following pandas dataframe and I would like to transpose it.



YEAR
CD_PRD
VL_JAN
VL_FEB
VL_MAR
VL_APR




2022
CD76
10000
8000
170000
58000


2022
CD92
15000
7500
86000
1200


2023
CD76
8000
12000
15000
5000


2023
CD92
12000
4560
10480
15600


2024
CD76
400
8000
45800
120


2024
CD92
56000
10200
150000
1500



What I need is to pivot the values columns names e.g.(VL_JAN   |  VL_FEB   |  VL_MAR   | VL_APR ) into rows, and the rows (CD-PRD) into lines to have the following dataframe at the end:



YEAR
MONTHS
VL_CD76
VL_CD92




2022
JAN
10000
15000


2022
FEB
8000
7500


2022
MAR
170000
86000


2022
ABR
58000
1200


2023
JAN
8000
12000


2023
FEB
12000
4560


2023
MAR
15000
10480


2023
ABR
5000
15600


2024
JAN
400
56000


2024
FEB
8000
10200


2024
MAR
45800
150000


2024
ABR
120
1500



I did the following, but it seems I miss something and did not managed to get the right dataframe structure.
df3 = df2.pivot(index='YEAR', columns=['CD_PRD'], values=['VL_JAN', 'VL_FEB', 'VL_MAR', 'VL_APR']).reset_index()
print(df3)

Any help would be amazing. Thanks!
Marcio

A possible solution, whose steps are:

The first step is to set the index of the dataframe df to the columns YEAR and CD_PRD using the set_index method.

Then, the stack method is used to pivot the columns into rows, creating a hierarchical index.

The unstack method is then applied to pivot the innermost level of the index back into columns.

The reset_index method is used to reset the index of the dataframe, turning the index back into columns.

The rename_axis method is used to remove the name of the axis.

The set_axis method is used to rename the columns of the dataframe to the list colnames.

Finally, the pipe method is used to apply a lambda function that uses the assign method to create a new column MONTH by removing the prefix VL_ from the values in the MONTH column using the str.replace method.


colnames = ['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'VL_CD76', 'VL_CD92']

(df.set_index(['YEAR', 'CD_PRD']).stack()
 .unstack(1).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
 .set_axis(colnames, axis=1)
 .pipe(lambda x: x.assign(MONTH = x['MONTH'].str.replace('VL_', ''))))

Output:
    YEAR MONTH  VL_CD76  VL_CD92
0   2022   JAN    10000    15000
1   2022   FEB     8000     7500
2   2022   MAR   170000    86000
3   2022   APR    58000     1200
4   2023   JAN     8000    12000
5   2023   FEB    12000     4560
6   2023   MAR    15000    10480
7   2023   APR     5000    15600
8   2024   JAN      400    56000
9   2024   FEB     8000    10200
10  2024   MAR    45800   150000
11  2024   APR      120     1500


Thank you! Is it possible to rename the values from columns (VL_JAN, VL_FEB) to something like JAN, FEB, etc.?

I have meanwhile updated my solution to accomplish that, @MarcioLino.

Awesome! Thank you @PaulS
